# Does accessing blob storage within Azure use bandwidth?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I am thinking about creating a Azure app service that accesses files from a Azure storage container, manipulates the file, and then returns the result to the end user. Does Azure consider transferring data from the storage blob to the App Service as bandwidth usage? I am wondering if doing this will incur a charge two times for every operation - once for blob -> app service and another for app service -> end user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure uses internal bandwidth across it's service fabric, so there is no charge for bandwidth utilization. However, any read/writes are transactions against storage, and there is a (nominal) cost. You can use the Azure calculators, based on your region, to determine and approximate costs for data storage + storage transaction. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/

Answer (score 2):

There is no bandwidth charge as long as the data remains within a single Azure region.

Answer (score 0):

As Neil mentioned, bandwidth within a region is not metered (between *any* services). You'll still be metered for outbound bandwidth from Web App to end user. And if you download blobs from storage in a different region to your Web App, that bandwidth *is* metered.

Also, if you ever choose to download direct from blob to end-user, that outbound bandwidth is also metered.